# Does the object which is the entry point of a Java program get garbage collected?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

If I have a class Sample and I have an instance method, instanceMethod in it.
The class has a main method where I create an object of Sample itself and call it's instanceMethod without using a reference variable.

like this:

new Sample().instanceMethod();

inside the main.

Since this object has NO reference, will the garbage collector collect it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java<sup>1</sup>, I don't believe the object can be collected while `instanceMethod()` is being executed. In the `main` method's stack frame there *is* a reference to the object, at least logically (the JIT compiler may elide it). The fact that you're not assigning it to a variable doesn't affect the bytecode very much.

Of course when `instanceMethod()` completes, the object *may* be eligible for garbage collection - but it may not. For example, `instanceMethod()` may store a reference to `this` in a static variable.

Basically it's not worth getting hung up over intricate corner cases - just rely on the GC collecting objects which can't be reached any more in any way, but not collecting objects which may still be in use.

---

<sup>1</sup> In .NET an object *can* still be garbage collected while an instance method is executing "in" the object, if the JIT compiler can prove that none of its variables will be read again. It's very confusing, and can cause very subtle bugs.

Comment: But say if instance method spawns multiple threads and they are reffered within Sample object. once instanceMethod is over.

won't references to thos threads will be lost if this obj is garbage collected ?

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar: The threads would still be running, and if those threads actually refer to the object, then that would keep the object alive too. But yes, if it *just* starts threads and remembers reference to those threads, then the object could be collected and those variables lost... but then you couldn't access those variables anyway, so it makes no difference.

Comment: Newer findings are, in Java [objects may get collected while instance methods are running](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26645534/2711488) as well. So Java and .NET are on par in this regard.