# new keyword and garbegcollection

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection, new-operator

I have a query related to `new` keyword.

1. What is the difference between

```
new Demo().abc();
```

and

```
Demo demo=new Demo();
demo.abc();
demo=null;
```

2. 
If I use first one then automatically garbage collector remove the memory?

My Question is:

how to remove memory for the below object:

```
new Demo().abc();
```

Answer (score 5):

**Case -1 :**

`new Demo().abc();`

Here, we are not maintaining any *explicit reference* to the newly created `Demo` instance. But inside the `abc()`, the `this` reference will point to the *newly* created instance. So, if the reference doesn't leak from `abc()`, as soon as the method returns, the newly created `Demo` instance will be ready for GC (As it becomes *unreachable* from any thread).

If there is a reference leak like this :

```
public void abc()
 {
  someOtherMethod(this); // starts another thread and does something else
  ...
 }
```

In the above case, even when `abc()` returns, the `Demo` instance created could still be reachable and thus will not be eligible for GC.

**Case -2 :**

```
Demo demo=new Demo();
demo.abc();
demo=null;
```

Here as soon as you set `demo` to `null` and assuming `abc()` doesn't leak the reference of `demo` to some other thread, your `demo` instance will become *unreachable* as soon as you set it to `null` and thus, it will be *eligible for GC*.

Comment: The `Demo` instance may even [get collected while `abc()` is running](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26645534/2711488). Well, after optimization, it might be the case that the code of `abc()` gets executed without a `Demo` instance ever be created.

Comment: @Holger - Yes. `JVM / JIT` has so many tricks up its sleeve.. :) .

Answer (score 0):

You don't have explicitly do anything to remove `"new Demo().abc()"` ,generally as long as  there are no strong references to this Demo() object it'll get Garbage Collected by JVM.

Comment: Strong reference means??

Comment: Strong references are regular references like Integer a = new Integer(10); here 'a' is said to have strong reference to the object of Integer class. In your case "new Demo().abc()" you can get strong references as mentioned by 'TheLostMind' in Case 1 , i.e. ' someOtherMethod(this);.... '

Comment: @tm.sauron You should explain the difference between a weak and strong reference. Why is a strong reference "strong"?