# Garbage collection seems to shutdown local executor and cause RejectedExecutionException

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection, jvm, google-http-client

Need help on an intermittent headache. The code is calling `com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest#executeAsync()` which basically has the following logic,

```
  @Beta
  public Future<HttpResponse> executeAsync(Executor executor) {
    FutureTask<HttpResponse> future = new FutureTask<HttpResponse>(new Callable<HttpResponse>() {

      public HttpResponse call() throws Exception {
        return execute();
      }
    });
    executor.execute(future);
    return future;
  }

  @Beta
  public Future<HttpResponse> executeAsync() {
    return executeAsync(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
  }
```

The call runs into `java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException` sometimes and from the log seems when this happens it's always accompanied by garbage collection. Below is a sample of the log pattern when this happens,

```
2017-09-26 11:04:56.039186 2017-09-26T11:04:56.012+0000: [GC pause (G1 Evacuation Pause) (young) 213M->50M(300M), 0.0262262 secs]
2017-09-26 11:04:56.048210 java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@71a0a39 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@36c306aa[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
2017-09-26 11:04:56.048212      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2063) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
2017-09-26 11:04:56.048214      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:830) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
2017-09-26 11:04:56.048216      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1379) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
2017-09-26 11:04:56.048218      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$DelegatedExecutorService.execute(Executors.java:668) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
2017-09-26 11:04:56.048220      at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.executeAsync(HttpRequest.java:1085) ~[google-http-client-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
2017-09-26 11:04:56.048222      at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.executeAsync(HttpRequest.java:1099) ~[google-http-client-1.21.0.jar:1.21.0]
```

Based on my understanding GC shouldn't clean up this executor since it hasn't gone out of scope yet, but judging by the log of the error this seems to be the behavior.

EDIT: Thanks for the quick responses. I probably need to clarify I cannot reproduce this either at my will otherwise I probably will have more clue. The code generally runs fine but this error does happen rarely and all we have is the log information I pasted for the symptom.

EDIT2: Clarification the code I pasted is not mine. It's the open source library `google-http-java-client` I'm using. So I have no way to change that. I sure can instead create a long-term `Executor` myself and call it with the first method, but I'm trying to understand what's the problem for now.

Comment: What shuts down your `Executor`? If you're spamming thousands of sleeping threads then having issues is very likely.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem using this code.

Comment: Are you somehow submitting a new task after having called shutdown() on the Executor?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, I probably meant life cycle, or sorry maybe I'm just bad at official terms. I thought in this case once `executeAsync()` is finished the executor is free for GC to take (shutdown is called inside this executor's finalizer). But when the exception happens the executor is still in use so GC should by no means touch it and cause it to shutdown right?

Comment: @jwils please note this part is not controlled by me, rather the google http client I'm using. As a user I simply call that `executeAsync()` in my code and the executor used is completely inside this `HttpRequest` class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `ExecutorService` returned by [`Executors#newSingleThreadExecutor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--) happens to be `ThreadPoolExecutor` wrapped in a `FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService`, an implementation detail that shuts down its wrapped `ExecutorService` on [finalization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#finalize--). We can tell the executor is shutdown from your logs

```
[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
```

Why is the object being finalized, though? You state

> Based on my understanding GC shouldn't clean up this executor since it
>   hasn't gone out of scope yet, but judging by the log of the error this
>   seems to be the behavior.

This is a common misconception. [Scope](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3) is a compile time feature that determines where a name can be used to refer to some entity in source code. It has no bearing on runtime garbage collection.

Garbage collection (and finalization) is controlled by reachability of objects. [The Java Language Specification states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-1.html#jls-1.1)

> When an object is no longer referenced, it may be reclaimed by the
>   garbage collector. If an object declares a finalizer, the finalizer is
>   executed before the object is reclaimed to give the object a last
>   chance to clean up resources that would not otherwise be released.
>   When a class is no longer needed, it may be unloaded.

The JVM will not garbage collect [reachable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1) objects

> A reachable object is any object that can be accessed in any potential continuing computation from any live thread.

As explained in the accepted answer (by an Oracle developer) for this question

- [finalize() called on strongly reachable object in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26642153/finalize-called-on-strongly-reachable-object-in-java-8)

reachability analysis allows

> for an object to be finalized and garbage collected even if there are
>   references to it in local variables on the stack

What you're seeing is the JVM making the decision that the `FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService` (and its `ThreadPoolExecutor`) is no longer reachable by a continuing computation from a live thread and finalizing it. That action shuts down the executor and the `RejectedExecutionException` is thrown when a task is submitted.

This is a known issue for that implementation and [bug JDK-8145304](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145304) was opened to discuss solutions (essentially just better documentation).

If it was up to me, `google-http-client` would change their implementation to use [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-) which isn't wrapped with a `FinalizableDelegatedExecutorService`. (I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/google/google-http-java-client/issues/372) to discuss a solution for the library.)

My suggestion is that you create your own `ExecutorService` (maybe with `newFixedThreadPool`) and use the overloaded  `executeAsync(Executor)` method.

---

The issue has been fixed, see [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-http-java-client/issues/372#event-2136931604).

Comment: Came for an answer, got an answer, plus a mini lesson. Wish I could give you two accepts, thanks!

Comment: There’s also [this statement in the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.6.1): “*Optimizing transformations of a program can be designed that reduce the number of objects that are reachable to be less than those which would naively be considered reachable. […]
Another example of this occurs if the values in an object's fields are stored in registers. The program may then access the registers instead of the object, and never access the object again. This would imply that the object is garbage. […]*”

Comment: By the way, if I know beforehand that only one job will get scheduled, I’d rather use `executeAsync(r -> new Thread(r).start());` which will imply automatic cleanup, without the risk of early finalization…

Comment: [reachabilityFence](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html#reachabilityFence-java.lang.Object-) is another option to counteract those optimizations