# Optimal way to use phantom references in Java 8, or use weak references instead?

Tags: java, java-8, weak-references, finalizer, phantom-reference

I am implementing a feature that reports an error when instances of my Java class are discarded before being "used" (for simplicity, we can define being "used" as having a particular method called).

My first idea is to use phantom references, which is often used as an improvement on `finalize()` methods. I would have a phantom reference class that would point to my main object (the one I want to detect whether it is discarded before being used) as the referrent, something like this:

```
class MainObject {
    static class MyPhantom extends PhantomReference<MainObject> {
        static Set<MyPhantom> phantomSet = new HashSet<>();
        MyPhantom(MainObject obj, ReferenceQueue<MainObject> queue) {
            super(obj, queue);
            phantomSet.add(this);
        }
        void clear() {
            super.clear();
            phantomSet.remove(this);
        }
    }
    MyPhantom myPhantom = new MyPhantom(this, referenceQueue);
    static ReferenceQueue<MainObject> referenceQueue = new ReferenceQueue<>();
    void markUsed() {
        myPhantom.clear();
        myPhantom = null;
    }
    static void checkDiscarded() { // run periodically
        while ((aPhantom = (MyPhantom) referenceQueue.poll()) != null) {
            aPhantom.clear();
            // do stuff with aPhantom
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am using Java 8, and in Java 8, phantom references are not automatically cleared when they are enqueued into the reference queue. (I know that this is fixed in Java 9, but unfortunately, I must use Java 8.) This means that, once the GC determines that the main object is not strongly reachable, and enqueues the phantom reference, it still cannot reclaim the memory of the main object, until I manually clear the phantom reference after I dequeue it in `checkDiscarded()`. I am concerned that, during the period of time between the GC enqueuing the phantom reference and me dequeueing it from the queue, the main object will remain in memory when it's unnecessary. My main object references many other objects which take a lot of memory, so I would not want it staying in memory for longer than without this feature.

To avoid this problem of the phantom reference preventing the main object from being reclaimed, I came up with the idea of using a dummy object as the referrent of the phantom reference instead of my main object. This dummy object will be referenced from my main object, so it will become unreachable at the same time as my main object. Since the dummy object will be small, I don't mind it not being reclaimed for longer period of time, as long as my main object will be reclaimed as soon as it's not reachable. Does this seem like a good idea, and is it really better than using the main object as the referrent?

```
class MainObject {
    static class MyPhantom extends PhantomReference<Object> {
        static Set<MyPhantom> phantomSet = new HashSet<>();
        MyPhantom(Object obj, ReferenceQueue<Object> queue) {
            super(obj, queue);
            phantomSet.add(this);
        }
        void clear() {
            super.clear();
            phantomSet.remove(this);
        }
    }
    Object dummyObject = new Object();
    MyPhantom myPhantom = new MyPhantom(dummyObject, referenceQueue);
    static ReferenceQueue<Object> referenceQueue = new ReferenceQueue<>();
    void markUsed() {
        myPhantom.clear();
        myPhantom = null;
    }
    static void checkDiscarded() { // run periodically
        while ((aPhantom = (MyPhantom) referenceQueue.poll()) != null) {
            aPhantom.clear();
            // do stuff with aPhantom
        }
    }
}
```

Another idea I am considering is to use weak references instead of phantom references. Unlike phantom references in Java 8, weak references are cleared when they are enqueued, so it does not prevent the referrent from being reclaimed. I understand that the reason why phantom references are usually used for resource cleanup, is that phantom references are only enqueued after the referrent is finalized and guaranteed to not be used anymore, whereas weak references are enqueued before being finalized, and so resources cannot be freed yet, and also the finalizer might resurrect the object. However, that's not a concern in my case, as I am not "cleaning up" any resources, but just making a report that my main object was discarded before being used, which can be done while the object is still in memory. My main objects also do not have a `finalize()` method, so there is no concern of resurrecting the object. So do you think weak references would be a better match for my case?

Comment: I don't see how you can ever possibly a hit with this system. The only reason a class gets loaded in the first place is because some other class refers to it, and it can't be unloaded until that referring class is. So as long as there is a referring class, i.e. a class which could call a method in the class of interest, the class of interest can never be unloaded.

Comment: When your object does not hold resources, why would “discarded before being used” be a problem worth reporting at all? Further, it’s worth reading [finalize() called on strongly reachable objects in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26642153/2711488), to keep in mind, “using an object” is not equal to “needing an object’s memory” and since you’re using Java 8, so [`reachabilityFence`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/Reference.html#reachabilityFence(java.lang.Object)) is not available, it will be challenging to  implement such a tracking correctly.

Comment: @user207421: This is not about class unloading, but about instances becoming unreachable and garbage collected.

Comment: @Holger: I have my use case for tracking this. I know that using a phantom reference as I described works. I am just worried about it keeping the object from being reclaimed until I check the queue, so I am trying to see if the following options could improve it: 1) using a dummy object as referrent, or 2) using weak references instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weak and phantom references are indeed equivalent when no finalization is involved. However, a common misconception is to assume that an object is only subject to finalizer reachability and potential resurrection when its own class has a `finalize()` method.

To demonstrate the behavior, we may use

```java
Object o = new Object();
ReferenceQueue<Object> q = new ReferenceQueue<>();
Reference<?> weak = new WeakReference<>(o, q), phantom = new PhantomReference<>(o, q), r;
// ...
o = null;
for(int cycles = 0, got = 0; got < 2; ) {
    while((r = q.remove(100)) == null) {
        System.gc();
        cycles++;
    }
    got++;
    System.out.println(
        (r == weak? "weak": r == phantom? "phantom": "magic unicorn")
      + " ref queued after " + cycles + " cycles");
}
```

This typically prints either,

```
phantom ref queued after 1 cycles
weak ref queued after 1 cycles
```

or

```
weak ref queued after 1 cycles
phantom ref queued after 1 cycles
```

as both references are truly treated the same in this case and there’s no preferred order when both are enqueued in the same garbage collection.

But when we replace the `// ...` line with

```java
class Legacy {
    private Object finalizerReachable;

    Legacy(Object o) {
        finalizerReachable = o;
    }
    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("Legacy.finalize()");
    }
}
new Legacy(o);
```

The output changes to something like

```
Legacy.finalize()
weak ref queued after 1 cycles
phantom ref queued after 2 cycles
```

as `Legacy`’s finalizer is enough to make the the object finalizer reachable and open the possibility to resurrect the object during finalization.

This doesn’t have to stop you from using this approach. You may decide that there’s no such finalizer in your entire application or accept this scenario as known limitation, to only apply if someone intentionally adds such a finalizer. JDK 18 has marked the `finalize()` method as *deprecated, for removal*, so this issue will disappear in the future without requiring you to take any action.

---

Still, your other approach using a dummy object with a `PhantomReference` will work as intended, having the phantom reference only enqueued when the dummy object and hence, also the outer object, is not even finalizer reachable anymore. The drawback is the (very) slightly higher memory consumption due to the additional dummy object.

Mind that the `markUsed()` method may set `dummyObject` to `null` to.

---

Another possible point of view is that when your feature is intended to log a wrong usage of your class, which should normally not happen, it doesn’t matter when it might temporarily consume more memory *when it happens*. When `markUsed()` has been called, the phantom reference is cleared and left to garbage collection without getting enqueued, so in the case of a correct usage, the memory is not held longer than necessary.

Comment: What about the idea that weak references might have an advantage over phantom references in Java 8, due to weak references being cleared before being enqueued, making the object immediately eligible to be reclaimed, but phantom references not being cleared when enqueued, so prevents the object from being reclaimed until you get the phantom reference out of the queue? Is that true?

Comment: Yes, for Java 8, it’s true. I also used `WeakReference` instead of `PhantomReference` under Java 8.